# How much plainext could be known without reducting security of RSA?

Tags: rsa

It is known, for example, that exposing 50% of the most significant bits of RSA private exponent *does not provide security risk* (when a small public exponent is used). So how to qualify *security degradation* of partial exposure of *plaintext* in RSA encryption? Can we say, for example, that exposing 50% of plaintext does not reduce security? And, is there a limit when it starts to actually reduce it?

I think that, probably, the answer should be related to 1) how many remaining bits are left to *brute force* (if 99% of plaintext is exposed it will be easy to just brute force the remaining 1%, so if non-exposed bits size is above 128 then security is 'not reduced'), and maybe 2) exposure for Coppersmith’s methods (if non-exposed bits size is more than $N^{1/e}$ than security is not degraded), but this should not even be relevant for $e=65537$ which is common.

Thus, can we say that the security of partial plaintext exposure of properly done RSA encryption is bound to as much is left for brute force?

Comment: do you speak of textbook RSA encryption?

Comment: @DrLecter Yes. Let's account padding as just part of plaintext.

Comment: Any pointer, or better short proof, that "_exposing 50% of most significant bits of RSA private exponent does not provide security risk_"? It seems there could be some additional conditions not stated here for this to hold.

Comment: @fgrieu Thanks, I corrected my statement. Reference http://imgur.com/a/ozrQo

Comment: It could be that "_exposing 1/2 of the most significant bits of the private exponent is not a security risk when a small exponent is used_" in your reference (with no accompanying proof) is to be read in the meaning it would have in the work of the Boneh et al. references cited; that is disclosing$$\big\lfloor d/2^{\lceil\log_2(N)/2\rceil}\big\rfloor.$$Conceivably, that could make some difference with disclosing$$\big\lfloor d/2^{\lceil\log_2(d)/2\rceil}\big\rfloor$$when $d=e^{−1}\bmod λ(n)$, and $p−1$, $q−1$ share a big factor, which can be by design, or (with not so small odd) by accident.